# Unique key error while indexing pdf files

Tags: solr, lucene

Im trying to index pdf files in solr 4.3.0 using the data import handler.

My request handler -

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport1" 
class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">  
    <lst name="defaults">  
      <str name="config">data-config1.xml</str>  
    </lst>  
  </requestHandler>
```

My data-config1.xml

```
<dataConfig>  
<dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" />  
<document>  
<entity name="f" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false" 
processor="FileListEntityProcessor" 
baseDir="C:\Users\aroraarc\Desktop\Impdo" fileName=".*pdf" 
recursive="true">  
<entity name="tika-test" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" 
url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">  
<field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
<field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
<field column="text" name="text"/>
</entity>  
</entity>  
</document>  
</dataConfig>
```

Now When i try and index the files i get the following error -

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id 
        at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getIndexedId(AddUpdateCommand.java:88) 
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:517) 
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:396) 
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:70) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:235) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:500) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:491) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:404) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:319) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:227) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:422) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:487) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:468)
```

This problem can be solved easily in case of database indexing but i dont know how to go about the unique key of a document. how do i define the id field (unique key) of a pdf file. how do i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique key is not mandatory in Solr.
So check the schema.xml for the uniquekey element and you can remove it e.g. `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`

Also, remove the required attribute from the id if exists.

```
<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

Remove the elevate component, if it refers to the id and results in exception.